# terraform grafana_provider datasource_influx2 encode not working? / How to provide an influx2 token?

Tags: terraform

This is a non issue:
Follow the description here:
https://github.com/grafana/terraform-provider-grafana/issues/691

Ignore the documentation provided here:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/grafana/grafana/latest/docs/resources/data_source

I wish to deploy influx2 datasources in grafana9 using terraform1.3.4.
The pipeline is stable, manual installation of influx is no problem, other resources like notification channels can be deployed without problem.

The problem appears to be the encoding of json values

The following configuration is submitted successfully but the created datasource in grafana lacks all json values

```
resource "grafana_data_source" "influxdb" {
  type          = "influxdb"
  name          = "influx_terraform"
  url           = "https://<url:port>"
 
  json_data_encoded = jsonencode({
      version = "Flux"
      organization = "myOrg"
      default_bucket = "bucket"
      tls_skip_verify = true
  })

  secure_json_data_encoded = jsonencode({
      auth_token = "token"
  })
}
```

The following snippet results in the values being properly set, safe for the token.

Also this way of doing is deprecated.

```
resource "grafana_data_source" "influxdb2" {
  type          = "influxdb"
  name          = "influx_terraform"
  url           = "https://<url:port>"
 
  json_data {
      version = "Flux"
      organization = "myOrg"
      default_bucket = "bucket"
      tls_skip_verify = true
  }

  secure_json_data {
      auth_token = "token"
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is not working? Are there any errors? If so, please add them to the quesiton.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There is no error. It just fails to effect. There is also no recognizable log feed regarding terraform provisioning in the grafana log

Comment: How does the failure manifest itself?

Comment: No log feed is not entirely accurate.

Upon terraform apply, the grafana log reads:
`... level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/api/datasources/20 status=404 ...`

Comment: The failure manifests as "missing token". Everything but the token is submitted, the secure_json_data.access_token is not.

Comment: Also, I have not yet found any example on how to define an influx2 datasource.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/grafana/grafana/latest/docs/resources/data_source#nested-schema-for-secure_json_data

Comment: Currently reading related information: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/grafana-data-source-influxdb-flux-support/21904  - DEAD

Comment: Yeah, I saw this comment for the `secure_json_data` argument: "To figure out what options a datasource has available, see its docs or inspect the network data when saving it from the Grafana UI".

Comment: the actual grafana provisioning requires the key "token". But that is not accepted, the "access_token" key is also without effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a non issue: Follow the description here: https://github.com/grafana/terraform-provider-grafana/issues/691

Ignore the documentation provided here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/grafana/grafana/latest/docs/resources/data_source

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).