# How to provide encoded json data to resources in cdktf for grafana

Tags: python, grafana, terraform-cdk

I appear to be an early adopter of cdktf for grafana using python.
The following config is successfully transmitted and accepted by grafana

```
    DataSource(self, "xxx",
    uid = "datasource_influxdb",
    type = "influxdb",
    name = "...",
    url  = "...",
    json_data= [DataSourceJsonData(
        default_bucket    = "xxx",
        http_method       = "POST",
        organization      = "xxx",
        version           = "Flux",
        tls_skip_verify   = "true"
    )]
    )
```

The documentation is unclear on how to provide `json_data_encoded` and `secure_json_data_encoded`.

I have a working terraform config: ([terraform grafana_provider datasource_influx2 encode not working? / How to provide an influx2 token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74402027/terraform-grafana-provider-datasource-influx2-encode-not-working-how-to-provi))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple python json encoding using `json.dumps(dict())`

```
    DataSource(self, "xxx",
    uid = "datasource_influxdb",
    type = "influxdb",
    name = "xxx",
    url  = "xxx
    json_data_encoded = json.dumps(
        dict(defaultBucket    = "xxx",
        httpMode       = "POST",
        organization      = "xxx",
        version           = "Flux",
        tlsSkipVerify     = True)
    ),
    secure_json_data_encoded = json.dumps(
        dict(token = "xxx")
    )
    )
```

Beware to use the actual keys required by grafana and ignore the mappings of cdktf